# Pointer that can reference a UITextView or a UITextField

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

I want to print a form that contains a mixture of UITextFields and UITextViews, doing exactly the same thing with each one regardless of its actual type. To keep the code clean I'd like to assign each item in the views array to the same variable in order to retrieve its printing parameters. I thought I could do this with a variable of type id, but I haven't hit on anything that will compile. The code below doesn't compile but it shows what I want to do. My thanks to anyone who tells me how to do this correctly.

```
    id theField;

    //for each field on the page
    for (j = offsetToFirstFormField; j < [self.fields count]; j++) {

        theField = [self.fields objectAtIndex: j];
        printStr = theField.text;
        if ([printStr length] > 0) {

            theFont =  [theField font];
            maxSize =  CGSizeMake(theField.frame.size.width, theField.frame.size.height);
            printStrSize = [printStr sizeWithFont:theFont constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
            printRect = CGRectMake((theField.frame.origin.x * xScale) + xOffset, (theField.frame.origin.y * yScale) + yOffset, printStrSize.width, printStrSize.height);
            [printStr drawInRect:printRect withFont:theFont];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use dot-syntax with `id` variables.  You have to stick with message-sending syntax.  For example, you have to change this:

```
printStr = theField.text;
```

to this:

```
printStr = [theField text];
```

If that doesn't fix it, edit your question and paste in the actual error messages you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your printable functionality in a protocol. So you will be using `id<Printable>` rather than `id`. Your protocol will have methods like `getText` `getFont`. Or you can use category to extend the existing classes.